# Azure Automation Powershell 5.1 Runbook - ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Azure Automation Powershell 5.1 Runbook unable to get json payload.

I am posting this in the body of the webhook request - I know this is correct.

This code works to get the parameters in 7.2 but I am using the exhangeonlinemanagement module which is having other issues in runbooks with 7.2. I need to get this working, so I wanted to use 5.1 for now.

What am I doing wrong?

All I need to do is get the parameters from the payload, but I keep getting this error:

> ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: . At line:11 char:31 +
> $Payload = $WebhookData | ConvertFrom-Json + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ +
> CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
>
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

```
[{
    "Alias": "jack", 
    "User" : "john"
}]
```

[image: Webhook request received by the runbook]

This is the code in my RunBook

```
param
(
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
    [object] $WebhookData
)

if ($WebhookData) {

    Write-Output $WebhookData.RequestHeader

    $Payload = $WebhookData | ConvertFrom-Json


    if ($Payload.RequestBody) { 

        $aliases = (ConvertFrom-Json $Payload.RequestBody)

            foreach ($x in $aliases)
            {
                $alias = $x.Alias
                $user = $x.User
                Write-Output "Alias: $alias"
                Write-Output "User: $user"
            }
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "Request Error"
    }


} else
    {
        Write-Output "Missing information";
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: I do not think json is valid.  Get the json and check with an online json checker.

Comment: This is powershell script for the runbook.

Comment: The error say JSON which most likely means it is a HTTP Request and the body is failing a json check.

Comment: This is why I asking for help.  I am using powershell in an azure a runbook to get payload. It creates its own WebhookData json which is throwing errors when trying to convert.

Comment: This is the line that is the problem - works in 7.2. But as stated above I need to use 5.1. 
$Payload = $WebhookData | ConvertFrom-Json
I am posting this in the webhook request
[{
 "Alias": "jack", 
 "User" : "john"
}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix.

$Payload = $WebhookData | ConvertFrom-Json was not needed.

I took this from the Microsoft example. So, I assumed this working.